# AngularJS ng-options default selected option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angular-ngmodel

How can you set a default option with ng-options?

I've set this in the controller (using the controller as syntax):

`this.myOption = this.myOptions[0];`

However, that's still returning a blank default option:

`<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>`

How can I set the default option to the first value in my model ("Item 1")?

[Here's a JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/gewebeqo/1/edit).

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv He is using `ng-model`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

either change:

`ng-options="value.id as value.label ...`

to:

`ng-options="value as value.label ...`

demo: http://jsbin.com/gewebeqo/4/

---

or use:

`this.myOption = this.myOptions[0].id;`

in the controller.

demo: http://jsbin.com/gewebeqo/3/

Answer (score 3):

ng-model needs the id of the option you want to select. Therefore you need to use `this.myOption = this.myOptions[0].id;` instead of `this.myOption = this.myOptions[0]`.